# Text mesh pro not disabling by script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having a problem with my game. I have a script ( that is listed below ) that is supposed to show a text for some time and then make it disappear. This script is being done through a game object with a trigger collider. This script is working fine with the first game object, but then it is not working for the next game instance where I've used it ( as seen in the video listed below ). May anybody tell me what's wrong in this instance and help me to fix this? Thank you!

Video link:https://streamable.com/zwjism

Script used for the first text trigger ( the attack text ):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class CollisionText : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI enemyWarning;
    public float duration = 4f;
    [SerializeField] private Animator anim;

    void Start()
    {
        enemyWarning.enabled = false;
    }


    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            StartCoroutine ( showText(other) );
        }
    }

    IEnumerator showText(Collider2D player)
    {
        enemyWarning.enabled = true; // displays text
        attackDemonstration();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(duration); // waits an amount of time x
        enemyWarning.enabled = false; // makes the text invisible
        Destroy(gameObject); // destroys the trigger after the x amount of time
    }

    void attackDemonstration()
    {
        for(int i=1; i<=3; i++)
        {
            anim.SetTrigger("Attack");
        }
    }
}
```

Script used for the second text trigger that doesn't disappear ( the test text ):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI enemyWarning;
    public float duration = 4f;
    [SerializeField] private Animator anim;

    void Start()
    {
        enemyWarning.enabled = false;
    }


    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            StartCoroutine(showText(other));
        }
    }

    IEnumerator showText(Collider2D player)
    {
        enemyWarning.enabled = true; // displays text
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(duration); // waits an amount of time x
        enemyWarning.enabled = false; // makes the text invisible
        Destroy(gameObject); // destroys the trigger after the x amount of time
    }
}
```

Comment: debug it.. do you get errors? why does showtext get passed a reference its not using, have you changed the value of duration in the inspector? its not recreatable from this

Comment: `// destroys the trigger after the x amount of time` ... no it does **not**! Instead you are destroying the `GameObject` where this `CollisionText` or `test` script is attached itself. Is your tag correct? In general rather use `.CompareTag("player")` instead of `.tag == "player"`

Answer (score 0):

Try activating before calling the StartCoroutine function. Sometimes we cannot make changes in IEnumerator due to some situations that I do not know the reason of. Maybe there is someone who knows better.

or

If you do something like this while you are defining it, you can try it too.

```
tmpScore = gameObject.AddComponent <TextMeshPro> ();
```

I hope it helps.

or

The duration value sounds too low and may change quickly. You can try printing something to the console with the debug.log command.